# Why does the clang compiler put these instructions at the start of every function which takes arguments?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I used clang to compile this code with `-S -emit-llvm`:

```
int sub2(int n) {
    return n - 2
}
```

And this is the code it outputted:

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind
define i32 @_Z4sub2i(i32) #0 {
    %2 = alloca i32, align 4
    store i32 %0, i32* %2, align 4
    %3 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
    %4 = sub nsw i32 %3, 2
    ret i32 %4
}
```

However, I could write the same function as:

```
define i32 @sub2(i32) #0 {
    %2 = sub i32 %0, 2
    ret i32 %2
}
```

Why does it adds those instruction? I am not sure about it, but it seems it's copying the argument.

Comment: Do you have optimizations enabled? Show the flags u use to compile

Comment: @ChrisBeck I used `-S -emit-llvm`

Comment: It is copying the argument to a local variable. With `-S -emit-llvm` you are generating unoptimized code so try `-S -emit-llvm -O3` or `-O2` to see something different. Why is it not automagically optimizing? Because you didn't ask the compiler to do magic so it generates a representation it probably has in the pre-generate AST (SSA based).

Comment: @FrankC. With `-O3` it acts as expected, but it converts `sub %2 2` to `add %2 -2` O.o

Comment: No surprises, I don't know what platform you are generating to but optimized instruction scheduling may be cause, it is a legit operation for sure.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you haven't run the mem2reg pass. The variables are considered to occupy space on the stack and are alloca'd.

If you try 
`opt --mem2reg filename.ll -S`
you will see that you get something similar to what you expected.

mem2reg is also a part of O1, O2, and O3.

The mem2reg pass tries to convert "variables" into llvm temporaries. It does this only for those variables who address is not taken.